# Shiny widgets do not work unless another widget is activated

Tags: r, shiny

I have a functional shiny app whose logic is described below:

**Logic of the app:**

The user chooses one of the Tests by using the selectInput() "Label". This is the main operation and then he is able to modify its name, for example Test 1 to Test A. Then the user can add items in the Test by the numericInput() "Items in Test". These are the total items. As you will see the number of "Items in Test" is the same with 'Avail' column in hot3 table for the choosen Test. With "Select Items" he can choose specific items to be displayed in the hot5 table. Then the user can click on the hot5 table to select a specific item and the number of selected items (or rows) is displayed in the hot3 table under "Sel" column for this specific Test. The 'Items chosen' just displayes the number of Items selected in "Select Items". Note that every modification that happens to the table is not dependent on the other widgets. That means for example that it is not necessary to change a Label Name.

**Issue :**

The issue is that right now the hot 3 table (in the left) is not updated unless I change the "Label" name which should not be like that as it is an optional feature like everything else. For example I may choose "Test 1" but I do not want to change its name. Then if I choose the submitbutton the table in the left is not updated. If I rename it to sth else (even "Test 1") it works. But it should work in any case.

```
library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(rhandsontable)
    #library(tidyverse)

    ui <- navbarPage(
      "Application",
      tabPanel("Booklets",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   uiOutput("tex2"),
                   rHandsontableOutput("hot3")
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   fluidRow(
                     wellPanel(
                       fluidRow(
                         column(4,
                                DT::dataTableOutput("hot5")
                         ),
                         column(4,
                                fluidRow(
                                  uiOutput("book3"),
                                  uiOutput("book6")

                                ),
                                fluidRow(
                                  uiOutput("book1"),
                                  uiOutput("book10"),
                                  uiOutput("book11")
                                ),
                                fluidRow(actionButton("submit","submit"))
                         )
                       ))
                   )
                 )
               )
      )
    )
    #server
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      rv<-reactiveValues()

      output$tex2<-renderUI({
        numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
      })

      output$book1<-renderUI({
        numericInput("bk1",
                     "Items in test",
                     value = 1,
                     min = 1)
      })

      output$book3<-renderUI({

        selectInput("bk3",
                    "Label",
                    choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))

      })


      output$book6<-renderUI({
        textInput("bk6", "Change to",
                  value=NULL
        )
      })


      output$book10<-renderUI({
        # changed from selectize
        selectizeInput(
          "bk10", "Select Items", choices =1:10000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
          options = list(maxItems = input$bk1))#changed from
      })
      output$book11<-renderUI({
        textInput("bk11", "Items chosen",
                  value = nrow(rt5())
        )
      })

      #rt4<-reactive({
      observe({
        req(input$text2)

        rv$rt4 = data.frame(
          SNo = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
          Test=paste(1:input$text2),
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          Avail=1L,
          Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      })

      observeEvent(input$submit,{

     # rt4 <- reactive({
        if (is.null( rv$rt4))
          return(NULL)

        if(!is.null(input$bk6) && input$bk6!=""){
          rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Avail"] <- input$bk1
          rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==(input$bk3), "Sel"] <- length(input$hot5_rows_selected)

          rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Label"] <- input$bk6
        }
        # if(!is.null(input$hot5_rows_selected) && input$hot5_rows_selected!=""){
        #
        # }
      })

      observeEvent(input$submit,{

        updateSelectInput(session,"bk3","Label", choices=rv$rt4$Label)
      }
      )


      rt55<-reactive({
        DF=data.frame(
          Id=  input$bk10,
          Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
          Pf=0,
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      })

      rt5<-reactive({
        DF=data.frame(
          Id=  input$bk10,
          Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
          Pf=0,
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
        cbind(id=rowSelected(), DF)
      })

      rowSelected <- reactive({
        x <- numeric(nrow(rt55()))
        x[input$hot5_rows_selected] <- 1
        x
      })

      output$hot5 <- renderDT(datatable(rt5()[,-1],
                                        selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                                                         selected = (1:nrow(rt5()[,-1]))[as.logical(rowSelected())],
                                                         target = "row"),rownames = F)
      )

      output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable({
        req(input$text2)
        rhandsontable(rv$rt4)
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this works for you.

```
    library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
#library(tidyverse)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("Booklets",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               rHandsontableOutput("hot3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 wellPanel(
                   fluidRow(
                     column(4,
                            DT::dataTableOutput("hot5")
                     ),
                     column(4,
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book3"),
                              uiOutput("book6")

                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book1"),
                              uiOutput("book10"),
                              uiOutput("book11")
                            ),
                            fluidRow(actionButton("submit","submit"))
                     )
                   ))
               )
             )
           )
  )
)
#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv<-reactiveValues()

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  output$book1<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk1",
                 "Items in test",
                 value = 1,
                 min = 1)
  })

  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3",
                "Label",
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))

  })


  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to",
              value=NULL
    )
  })


  output$book10<-renderUI({
    # changed from selectize
    selectizeInput(
      "bk10", "Select Items", choices =1:10000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
      options = list(maxItems = input$bk1))#changed from
  })
  output$book11<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk11", "Items chosen",
              value = nrow(rt5())
    )
  })

  #rt4<-reactive({
  observe({
    req(input$text2)

    rv$rt4 = data.frame(
      SNo = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
      Test=paste(1:input$text2),
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      Avail=1L,
      Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit,{

    # rt4 <- reactive({
    if (is.null( rv$rt4))
      return(NULL)

    if(!is.null(input$bk6) && input$bk6!=""){
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Avail"] <- input$bk1
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==(input$bk3), "Sel"] <- length(input$hot5_rows_selected)

      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Label"] <- input$bk6
    }
    else
    {
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Avail"] <- input$bk1
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==(input$bk3), "Sel"] <- length(input$hot5_rows_selected)

      #rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Label"] <- input$bk6

    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit,{

    updateSelectInput(session,"bk3","Label", choices=rv$rt4$Label)
  }
  )


  rt55<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })

  rt5<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    cbind(id=rowSelected(), DF)
  })

  rowSelected <- reactive({
    x <- numeric(nrow(rt55()))
    x[input$hot5_rows_selected] <- 1
    x
  })

  output$hot5 <- renderDT(datatable(rt5()[,-1],
                                    selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                                                     selected = (1:nrow(rt5()[,-1]))[as.logical(rowSelected())],
                                                     target = "row"),rownames = F)
  )

  output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable({
    req(input$text2)
    rhandsontable(rv$rt4)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks a lot!